# GoCardless - Create a bill under a pre-auth - Reponse

Tags: php, gocardless

I am creating a bill under a pre-auth using PHP from GoCardless. According to their [documentation](https://developer.gocardless.com/legacy/php/#create-a-bill-under-a-pre-auth) the response will return a `bill` object.

I have to check some special logic depending on the `pass` or `failure` of the payment.

Does anybody know what GoCardless will return if the payment was not successful? Is it `false` or the `bill` object with some status?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can check if returned value is not instance of `bill`